# Java Try Catch Decorator

Tags: exception, decorator

I have a class with many functions

```
public class Test {
        public void a() {
            try {
                doSomething1();
            } catch (AException e) {
                throw new BException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            }
        }

        public void b() {
            try {
                doSomething2();
            } catch (AException e) {
                throw new BException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
```

In each method, an exception of certain type is caught and converted to another exception and thrown.

I want to remove duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may remove duplication using lambda:

- The `CallableEx` takes any exception, in case you are working with checked exception. You would not need it if `AException` was an unchecked exception. `Callable` interface won't help you much because it throws an `Exception` and not your `AException`: you would have to check for instance and so on.
- You could probably write the body instead of `this::doSomething1`, but I advise against it: this makes the code clearer and it separates concerns.

You could probably also use an annotation processor to do the same job and to rewrite the method in order to wrap your `AException` into a `BException`. You would not have duplication in your Java code, but your bytecode certainly will.

Here the example with lambda:

```
public class Test {
  @FunctionalInterface
  interface CallableEx<T, E extends Exception> {
    T run() throws E;
  }

  private <T> void handleException(CallableEx<T, AException> forrestGump) {
    try {
      return forrestGump.run();
    } catch (AException e) {
      throw new BException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());    
    }
  }

  public String a() {
    return handleException(this::doSomething1);
  }

  public int b(int a, int b) {
    return handleException(() -> this.doSomething2(a, b));
  }

  public <T extends Foobar> void c(T my) {
    handleException(() -> this.doSomething3(my));
  }

  private String doSomething1() {return "A";}
  private int doSomething2(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
  private <T extends Foobar> void doSomething3(T my) {my.foo();}

}
```

Comment: What if the both functions take arguments(different no / types), and return types are also different?

Comment: You get your example; see method b :)